# Is there a way to fill NaNs at the end of a column with values from another column at the beginning in Python?

Tags: python

So I have two columns for example A & B and they look like this:

```
A           B
1           4
2           5
3           6
NaN         NaN
NaN         NaN
NaN         NaN
```

and I want it like this:

```
A
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your data is in two columns in a DataFrame, you can append B values to the end of A values, then drop the NA values with np.nan != np.nan trick. Here's an example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {
    'A': [1,2,3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'B': [4,5,6, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
A           B
1           4
2           5
3           6
NaN         NaN
NaN         NaN
NaN         NaN

# np.nan == np.nan trick 
>>> df['A'] == df['A']
0 True
1 True
2 True
3 False
4 False
5 False
Name: A, dtype: bool

x = pd.concat([df['A'], df['B']])
>>> x
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
0    4.0
1    5.0
2    6.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
dtype: float64

x = x[x == x]
>>> x
A
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy, it could be something like:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])
B = np.array([4, 5, 6, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])

C = np.hstack([A[A < np.infty], B[B < np.infty]])
print(C) # [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might want is:

`import pandas as pd`

`a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, None, None, None])`

`b = pd.Series([4, 5, 6, None, None, None])`

`print(pd.concat([a.iloc[:3], b.iloc[:3]]))`

And if you are just looking for non-NaN values feel free to use .dropna() in Series.